# How to get distance value from the xml file?

Tags: php, xml

I tried to fetch the distance in KM from this xml data. But Its not giving me a value. I am new in PHP so If any one can help would be appreciated.

```
 <DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>Kolkata, West Bengal, India</origin_address>
<destination_address>Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>140212</value>
<text>1 day 15 hours</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>2051694</value>
<text>2,052 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Thank you

Comment: is it a string or a file?

Comment: What have you done so far ? Can you show us your code ?

Comment: I am trying this
$xml=simplexml_load_file('Google XML API url for distance matrix') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
var_dump($xml);
foreach($xml->children() as $books) { 
    echo $books->distance->text . ", "; 
}

Comment: @user3443037 Please edit your post to include your code. It's impossible to read code typed into a comment box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:-

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
<DistanceMatrixResponse><status>OK</status><origin_address>Kolkata, West Bengal, India</origin_address><destination_address>Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</destination_address><row><element><status>OK</status><duration><value>140212</value><text>1 day 15 hours</text></duration><distance><value>2051694</value><text>2,052 km</text></distance></element></row></DistanceMatrixResponse>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo "Value:".$xml->row->element->distance->value."\n";
echo "Text:".$xml->row->element->distance->text."\n";
?>
```

Use $xml as dictionary or object to refer to the element whichever you need.

Comment: In case you get error like "simplexml_load_string not found", you can install php-xml package along with php